# correct implementation of add method in eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, split

I'm trying to do a tutorial with SharedPreferences here [Simple Multiple Selection Checkboxes](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/) its appears that all of my other code is fine but I get an error message of arguments not being applicable. I guess in this tutorial they are trying to add some values to an array. This is what i've tried but i still get an error.

```
private void LoadSelections() {
    // if the selections were previously saved load them

    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settingsActivity.contains(SETTING_TODOLIST)) {
        String savedItems = settingsActivity
                .getString(SETTING_TODOLIST, "");

        this.selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));
        int count = this.mainListView.getAdapter().getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String currentItem = (String) this.mainListView.getAdapter()
                    .getItem(i);
            if (this.selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                this.mainListView.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }

        }

    }
}


    private ArrayList<string> PrepareListFromXml() {
    ArrayList<string> cheeseItems = new ArrayList<string>();
    XmlResourceParser ingredientsXML = getResources().getXml(R.xml.ingredients);

    int eventType = -1;
    while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {

            String strNode = ingredientsXML.getName();
            if (strNode.equals("item")) {

                cheeseItems.add(ingredientsXML.getAttributeValue(null,"title"));

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you get an error message, please post it as well. People don't have second sight.

Comment: theres only a red line under add() and the details of the error says "The method add (R.string) in the type ArrayList <R.String> is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: Uh, `string` and `String` are not the same thing in Java. Note the `S`'s.

Comment: uh @spoike we could have done without the smart remark. and i was not aware of this, this is why i have asked. and all of the "strings" should have a lowercase "s" typo.

Comment: @Far That was a hint. Check answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing your types up, `R.string` is not the same as Java's `String` type.

The method [`getAttributeValue(String, String)`](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributeValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on the parser object returns object of the type `String` which you are trying to put it in a generic list that takes another kind of type.

So you can do two things:

1. Change the generic type of the list to `ArrayList<String>` and the signature of the `PrepareListFromXml` method to return of that type.
2. You need to do a conversion from `String` to `R.string` before you add it to the list.

Comment: oh ok, i don't think i quite get it. so should i convert `code` String strNode = ingredientsXML.getName(); `code` This code is actually from a tutorial, and I'm fairly new to programming in java. Thanks for your answer :-)